# How do I redirect the output of a Perl script to another file in %TEMP%?

Tags: perl

I need a Perl script on Windows which deletes the newline characters from a file and merges all the lines into one line and then writes into another file into the `%temp%` directory on a Windows system. For example, this script is to delete newlines and create a single line and write into another file in `%TEMP%`.

I have script which deletes the newlines but the output goes to STDOUT. I am not able to create a file in `%TEMP%` and redirect the output to that file.

Following is my script which is not working:

```
my $inFile = $ARGV[0];
$ENV{'TEMP'} = 'C:\\TEMP';

if ($inFile eq "") {
    print "Input file is missing\n";
    print "perl file_into_one_line.pl <input fil>\n";
    exit 0;
}

open(INFILE, "< $inFile") || die "$0, FEJL: can't open $inFile: $!";
foreach (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if (eof()) {    # check for end of last file
        print "$_\n";
    } else {
        open FILE, ">$ENV{'TEMP'}//temp//tst.txt" or die;
        print FILE "${_}$separator";
    }
}

close(INFILE);
```

Comment: Please include the scripts you have written so far.

Comment: You can run your script like this: `perl myscript.pl >%TEMP%/file.txt`

Comment: `inFile` can be `undef`, so check `!defined $inFile || $inFile eq ""`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that %TEMP% is DOS syntax for accessing a environment variable. You can access the value of environment variables inside perl through the %ENV hash like so:

```
$ENV{k}
```

where k is a string expression that gives the name of the variable. Try this in your windows command line:

```
perl -e "print $ENV{'TEMP'};"
```

You should be able to do the rest from here on.

Answer (score 0):

The script should be:

```
my $separator = " "; # I think you should have this some where~~~

my $inFile = $ARGV[0];
$ENV{'TEMP'} = 'C:\\TEMP';

if ($inFile eq "") {
    print "Input file is missing\n";
    print "perl file_into_one_line.pl <input fil>\n";
    exit 0;
}

open(INFILE, "< $inFile") || die "$0, FEJL: can't open $inFile: $!";
open FILE, ">$ENV{'TEMP'}\\tst.txt" or die $!;
foreach (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print FILE "${_}$separator";
}

print FILE "\n";

close(INFILE);
close(FILE);
```

Comment: After the ast line there is no `$separator`. So instead of the `foreach` loop I could suggest sg like `print FILE join $separator, map {chomp; $_} <INFILE>;`